# Permission error on shared host for gem command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm getting an error each time I attempt to use `gem install sass` (or `gem install` anything, really).

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91:in `read': Permission denied - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/passenger-3.0.18.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:91:in `load_specification'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:153:in `load_gems_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:152:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:152:in `load_gems_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:149:in `reverse_each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:149:in `load_gems_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:345:in `refresh!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:78:in `from_gems_in'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:58:in `from_installed_gems'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:883:in `source_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:81:in `init_gemspecs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/gem_path_searcher.rb:13:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:841:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:841:in `searcher'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:840:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:840:in `searcher'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:479:in `find_files'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:983:in `load_plugins'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1139
    from /usr/bin/gem:8:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/gem:8
```

Because this is a shared host, I don't have access to /usr/lib/ruby. I contacted a2hosting but they told me they don't support Ruby on Rails and to post about it here. So I guess that's an indication that there is some way to fix it myself? There is a RubyGems app on the a2hosting CPanel, but it doesn't work either:

[image: CPanel doesn't work when I try to install SASS]

I suspect this is because it just uses the same commands I'm using, and thus throws the same error.

I have installed rvm on the server, however. Perhaps there is a workaround using that?

Comment: Ruby's `1.8` support is deprecated. Anything less then Ruby `2.2.2` might run into issues on new/updated gems. Try using the older version of the gem... or a newer version of Ruby.

Comment: @Myst: As I said, though, `gem instal`l inherently just doesn't work. So that's an unrelated issue. I did try updating Ruby but that too didn't work. I got a memory allocation error.

Comment: I guess I skipped the `gem install [anything]` when I noticed the Ruby version. It could be a permission issue. You could probably install a Ruby version manager (`rvm` or `rbenv`) which will allow you to install gems only for your own user's account, circumventing the privilege issues (no root privileges required)... However, installing these might not be easy if your account doesn't let you install stuff...

Comment: One last thing: This isn't a Ruby on Rails issue, it's a Ruby / system issue and your hosting provider should be supporting you on this (and they should have been offering an updated Ruby version too, but it is what it is).

Comment: @Myst: Thanks. Yeah, I was pretty confused when they told me to go elsewhere, but I've updated my ticket so hopefully they'll recognize the issue. I've already tried RVM but it throws an error when I attempt to install a version of Ruby, so I'll try using rbenv.

Comment: sounds about right. I used `rbenv` myself because of installation issues.